# Woocommerce checkout order received page taking long time to load

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I click on the "place order" of the checkout page, the order gets placed. But the loading icon is still there for more than 30 sec. Then it shows order received thank you page.

How to speed up that process?
link: https://chatkatori.online/

Comment: It was a normal load for me took 3 seconds. Just in case check on different connection/wi-fi. Also turn on error log on in wp-config and check warning if you have any.May be any old plugin with deprecated code has any warnings?

Comment: using any checkout plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily deactivate jetpack plugin and check the order. I see errors in console.

Comment: Not working. The problem was there before installing Jetpack.

Comment: did you try this? :   Just in case check on different connection/wi-fi. Also turn on error log on in wp-config and check warning if you have any.May be any old plugin with deprecated code has any warnings?

Comment: I tried it. But didn't work. Thanks. Giving a try to see error log.